# Program camera app to take multiple exposures?

Tags: samsung, camera

I'm trying to create some HDR images by taking photos with multiple exposures. I have the "Kenu Stance" tripod for my Samsung Galaxy S9+, but ultimately, it's hard to keep the camera 100% steady in between shots as I have to tap the screen to change exposures and, well, it's a large phone so it will still pivot a bit when touched as the tripod is fixed on a small part of the phone (the USB-C jack).

Does anyone know of a way to program the phone/camera app to take three photos in a row, with different settings (like ISO and Shutter speed)? Or perhaps, if there already is a camera app out there that allows this? This way I could just connect my headset to the phone, click the shutter button once and be certain the phone is 100% steady during all the photos.

Comment: Izzy is a moderator here. Please see his list of curated [camera apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera) that may help.

Comment: Several there that do exactly what you describe.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions? No offense but i get a headache from looking at that page.